# Special character to html?

Tags: html, character, ascii

I'm trying to display the symbol below ad html for my website, does anyone know how to find this one as it doesn't show in dreamweaver and is proving to be a nightmare to find.

'ş'

the ascii for it is html 350-0

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: It is not an ASCII character. What encoding are you using on your site? If it is a Unicode encoding such as UTF8, this will show up just fine.

Comment: Please mark useful answers in your questions as "Accepted" in old questions. This will encourage community members to answer any new questions you place on this site and make the old ones more informative (as you can quickly find the answer that has the solution).

Comment: And further to @Oded's comment… if you aren't using a Unicode encoding: You should be. I can't think of any reason to continue using a legacy encoding in 2005 and we're some way past that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character you included in your question (ş) is U+015E LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CEDILLA. Its Unicode number is 015F in hexadecimal, 351 in decimal, so it can be included in HTML using the reference `&#x15f;` or, equivalently, `&#351;`.

As you mention the number 350 (which cannot possibly be an ASCII number for anything, since ASCII ends at 127), you might actually mean “Ş”, U+015E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CEDILLA, representable as `&#x15e;` or, equivalently, `&#350;`.

If you need numbers for other characters, check out http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/#links (not authoritative, but reliable and handy).

Answer (score 1):

```
&#350;
```

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: I've tried the &#350; and my webpage just shows the code as a pose to the character.

Also I'm not to sure what the encoding is, its just standard UK dreamweaver settings I'm using

Answer (score 0):

For any special characters, you can copy the character(s) and paste in the top box in this 2-way character-to-entity converter. Then just click on "convert" and grab your HTML entity characters.

http://www.gooplusplus.com/entity.html

This online utility converts to both HTML numeric and unicode entities + URL encoded

You can also just add the special characters as a parameter to the URL:

http://www.gooplusplus.com/entity.html?YOUR-SPECIAL-CHARS